# Rails 4.2: display postgres array value in view form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

There is a string array `segment` defined in psql. Here is the db migrate file:

```
t.string    :segment, array: true, default: []
```

When a value for `segment` is entered, the value is put within `{}` and is saved into the psql correctly. Here is a value in `postgres`:

```
{#6CF511,#EDF511,#F51111}
```

But when this value is displayed in view with the code below:

```
<%= f.input :segment, :label => ('Seg Range Color Choices')' %>
```

But the value displayed is not correct:

```
[&quot;#6CF511&quot;, &quot;#EDF511&quot;, &quot;#F51111&quot;]
```

Every value is appended `&quot;` before and after. Also the `[]` instead of `{}` is used. The following `jquery` code is used to filled out the value:

```
$('#dashboard_detail_segment').val("<%=rpt_detail.segment%>");
```

In debug, `rpt_detail.segment` = `array[3]`. `rpt_detail.segment.join(',')` can be used to turn the array into a string of "#6CF511, #EDF511, #F511112" and this may be one way to display. My question is that is there other `natural` way to display the `segment` in `Rails` view?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`raw`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper/raw) method so that Rails will not html escape the output.

```
$('#dashboard_detail_segment').val("<%= raw rpt_detail.segment %>");
```